# Calculate the thickness of material a ray passes through crossing a metal pipe

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a metal pipe of internal radius **R** and wall thickness **W**. I fire a ray across the pipe's cross-section, perpendicular to its longitudinal axis, so that at its closest point the ray is distance **d** from the centre of the cross-section.

How can I calculate the thickness of material **T** passed through by the ray? Clearly when **d=0**, **T=2W** and when **d>=R+W, T=0**.

Comment: It probably sounds like a homework question, but it's actually for a real-life software model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Pythagoras theorem applied twice.

Let $T_1 = \sqrt{(R+W)^2 - d^2}$ if $d \le R+W$, or $T_1 = 0$ otherwise. This is the path-length through the material in a solid pipe that has no internal hole. Then let $T_2 = \sqrt{R^2 - d^2}$ if $d \le R$, or $T_2 = 0$ if $d > R$. This is the path-length through the "air" inside the pipe. Then the answer is $T = T_1 - T_2$.

Comment: I hadn't seen that at all, thanks. However surely the basic equation we're using should be $T = 2\sqrt{R^2 - d^2}$

Comment: You're right. Sorry. Factors of 2 everywhere.